# DIV background color/image wont show

Tags: html, css, background

I got a little problem with a website I'm currently working on. The background color/image I declare in an extern css file wont shown in my page.

Never had this issue before and I really can't figure out why this is not working..

My Code:

```css
html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
}

#navigation {
 width: 100%;
 height: 5%;
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-left: 60%
 background-image: url(./img/nav_bg.png);

}

#nav-ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

#navi-li {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

#server {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #336699;
}

#evocity {
 width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="DE-de">
 <head>
  <title>DIAMOND DarkRP</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="language" content="de">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Garry's Mod, GMOD, DarkRP, Roleplay, Dimaond">
  <meta name="description" content="DIAMOND DarkRP - Forum, Teamspeak und weitere Informationen zum Diamond DarkRP Server">
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <meta name="audience" content="alle">
  <meta name="page-topic" content="Gameserver">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="navigation">
  <ul id="nav-ul">
   <li id="navi-li">Home</li>
   <li id="navi-li">Server</li>
   <li id="navi-li">TeamSpeak</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="server">
  <img src="./img/evocity.jpg" id="evocity" alt="EvoCity v33x">
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using an absolute path, it's likely your code is looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: Everything else in the style sheet works except for `background-image` and `background-color`? Or do you mean that the whole style sheet is not loaded?